# Incorrect output despite correct value of final variable in LeetCode

Tags: python-3.x, methods, return, permutation

Apologies if this is the wrong platform to ask but I couldn't find a discussion tab on LeetCode, so I thought this might be the best platform.

For the Next Permutation (31) problem on LeetCode, the nums list must be changed to reflect the next greatest permutation. [1,2,3] to [1,3,2], [3,2,1] to [1,2,3] and [1,1,5] to [1,5,1], etc. This value shouldn't be returned by the function but changed in place.

Now my code gives the correct output if I check using a print statement, but this isn't always correctly reflected in the output for some reason, and I'm not able to figure out why.

This is my code-

```
class Solution:
    def nextPermutation(self, nums: List[int]) -> None:
        """
        Do not return anything, modify nums in-place instead.
        """
        def recur(l,n,x):
            a=l[n-x:n]
            maxx=a[0]
            ind=0
            for i in range(1,x):
                if a[i]>maxx:
                    temp=a[i]
                    a[i]=a[ind]
                    a[ind]=temp
                    return l[:n-x]+a
            if x==n-1:
                l.sort()
                return l
            return recur(l,n,x+1)
        nums=recur(nums,len(nums),2)
```

Since the parent (or `__main__` code) isn't included on LeetCode, I assume the last value of the nums variable is accessed which should work.

There's a few similar questions, where apparently the issue is related to global and static variables which I honestly didn't understand, so I thought doing it using a for loop instead of a recursive function might eliminate any variable name related issue. But the code below had the same issue.

```
for x in range(2,n):
    a=nums[n-x:n]
    maxx=a[0]
    ind=0
    for i in range(1,x):
        if a[i]>maxx:
            temp=a[i]
            a[i]=a[ind]
            a[ind]=temp
            nums=nums[:n-x]+a
            t=True
            break
        if t:
            break
    else:
        nums.sort()
```

Comment: Your code is *not* changing the given list in-place. It creates new lists, and just assigns them back to `nums`, but that is still a different list. It doesn't magically abandon the newly created list and copies everything over to the original list.

Comment: Note that you have more problems than that. Even if you ignore this issue, it still produces wrong results. Try for instance `[1,3,2]`... So then what will be your question? You can assign to the original array by making the assignment `nums[:] = ` instead of `nums =`, but as indicated, you'll not pass the code challenge.

Comment: @trincot yup ran into that problem, re-evaluating my logic. Also understood that I'm not changing the list in place, but why is that a problem? Doesn't using an assignment operator mean everything should get copied over to the original list?

Comment: There is no copying over.